# getElementByTagName iteration unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, getelementsbytagname

I'm building this webpage where I want some subheadings to dropdown their hidden content when clicked on.... I did manage to make them all working triggers but they don't work exactly as intended.
Since each subheading and its content is contained within a SECTION tag, I decided to gather all elements with that tag by using "getElementsByTagName" in the JS file and iterate through each of them with a FOR loop, like this:

```
let section;

for (let i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('section').length; i++)
    {
        section=document.getElementsByTagName('section')[i];//This makes the "SECTION" variable become each one of the sections (which contain a subheading and a paragraph each)

        section.children[0].onclick= function()
            {//The first child element of each SECTION is the subheading, the second one is the paragraph
                if(section.children[1].style.display==='inline-block')
                    {
                        section.children[1].style.display='none';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        section.children[1].style.display='inline-block';
                    }
            }
    }
```

Now, the problem is that for some reason, while I can see that the "for" loop must be working since the "onclik" event is indeed taking each of the subheadings as a trigger element... **I can't understand why clicking on any of the subheadings, always drops down only the content on the last SECTION, it doesn't make sense to me, help please!!**

You can view all the files for the webpage here: https://github.com/SerGit-MondraHub/my-web/tree/public

And you can see it in action here:
https://sergit-mondrahub.github.io/my-web/

Comment: I would recommend using `document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach((section) => { /* your code here */ })`. That way you're only querying the DOM once and `section` is properly scoped. To answer your question though, move `let section` **inside** the loop.

Comment: you are changing value of section on every iteration, so after the for loop ends, section will be the last node of document.getElementsByTagName('section')

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... I moved `let section` inside the loop like @Phil suggested and it worked like a charm!! You're a life saver man, I checked out a short lesson on loops about 3 weeks ago and I know it made sense changing the scope of the variable from global to local and the other way around but now I can't remember why... would you be so kind as to explain the logic of how instructions are flowing in this particular solution as opposed to my original code?

Comment: There's a really thorough discussion linked at the top of your post

Comment: Yeah sorry, I only started reading it after posting the comment, my bad... Anyway, regarding the other solution you suggested @Phil I remember I had tried iterating with `forEach` through `getElementsByTagName` but I couldn't make it work so I resorted to the "for" loop instead...  I wonder if it was because of an error of mine or if `getElementsByTagName` just isn't meant to work with `forEach` and in that case: Why does `querySelectorAll` doesn't have that problem?